# PHP i want to know what is the error in this line

Tags: php

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK1CZ.png)

this is code is use to show a red color in the datatable if its empty and when the table as a data if will turn into white.

```
   <td class="<?php
    if (empty($log->ICS)) {
        echo "noactioncell";
    }
    else
    {
      
    }
    ?> text-center align-middle" >

    <?php
    if (!empty($log->issued)) {
          echo $log->issued;

    }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: This code looks okay, just Sublime text (I think it's ST from screenshot) can't highlight it correctly. Use better IDE, or don't mix PHP and HTML.

Comment: yes i had been trying to debug it in my previous view in codeigniter it does not show a error but when i make a new one and paste it to another view that i had made it give a error like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with your code, but with the syntax highlighting in your editor. **You should set syntax to PHP.**

If you're using Sublime,

```
ctrl+shift+p
```

then type `Set Syntax:PHP`, and hit `Enter`

Also, you can beautify your code a little bit by omitting the unnecessary `else` part or make even better as

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->ICS) ? "noactioncell" :''; ?> text-center align-middle">
    <?php echo !empty($log->issued) ? $log->issued : '';?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have opengin `"` in `class="`

and the closing of `"` in `echo "`

try using `'` inseated of `"`
for `echo 'noactioncell';`

```php
<td class="<?php
   if (empty($log->ICS)) {
       echo "noactioncell";
   }
   else
   {
     
   }
   ?> text-center align-middle" >

   <?php
   if (!empty($log->issued)) {
         echo $log->issued;

   }
   ?>
</td>
```